# Video in html from local path

Tags: html, video

I'm new to web dev, I want that the web app will show videos, since I dont want to create folder within my projrct(heavy files) I want to read the video path from the local server that the backand located.

i need somethind like:

```
<video controls="controls">
        <source src="D:/videos/Movies/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

but his doesn't show the video

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: the videos have to be in a path that the webserver can see and deliver to the viewer. You don't need to create the path in your project, but on the server where you are deploying they should be in a path there (relative to the deployment root) and you reference that path in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Go to the mp4 when it's in the other directory and right click on the properties. copy the file path and then paste it in (and precede it by file://). make sure you turn the slashes to turn forward in the file path.

it should look something like this

```
file:///F:/Users/yourname/folder/subfolder/sample.mp4
```

exam :

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay>
        <source src="file:///F:/Users/yourname/folder/subfolder/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: I'm getting `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/videos/vid1.mp4` error

Comment: i your html or php file is uploaded to server, then video should have to upload in server same or any to read them.

Comment: please check and insert correct video path , will load in video tag.